# ajax forms and results in popup window

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in `DoComment.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DT.KazBilet.Objects.PublicationComment>" %>
<div class="wrap">
    <h4>Comment</h4>
    <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoComment", "Publication", new {id = Model.Publication.OID, parentId = Model.OID},new AjaxOptions()))
      {%>    
    <%=Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.Text) %>    
    <%-- <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 152px;"></textarea>--%>
    <input type="submit" value="Publish" class="btn ok_btn" />
    <%}%>
</div>
```

This is my controller's action:

```
public JsonResult DoComment(PublicationComment model, int id, int parentId)
        {
            PublicationRepository.SaveComment(User.Identity.Name,id, parentId, model.Text);

            return Json(new {
                 Message = "You comment on moderation"
                 });
        }
```

I want that user clicks on Publish button then show popup window where will be written text from `Message`.
Can you help me(some code)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `OnSuccess` javascript event in the AJAX options and then show the JSON result you have retrieved the way you like (new window, div, ...):

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "DoComment", 
    "Publication", 
    new { id = Model.Publication.OID, parentId = Model.OID },
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess" })
) %>
```

and then you would define the `onSuccess` javascript function. Depending on whether you use jQuery or MicrosoftAjax the implementation of this function might slightly vary and more specifically the way to retrieve the JSON result.

For example if you are using MicrosoftAjax (obsolete now):

```
var onSuccess = function(e) {
    var json = e.get_response().get_object();    
    alert(json.Message);
};
```

and if you are jQuery:

```
var onSuccess = function(json) {
    alert(json.Message);
};
```

Comment: @user348173, maybe you have javascript errors? Maybe you haven't included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page (if you are using jQuery) or the `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` script? Those scripts are required i order to AJAXify the form. Maybe there is some other problem with your code? It's impossible to say because you haven't shown your code. You could use FireBug to debug your javascript.